# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException since Spring 3.1.3

Tags: exception, javabeans, spring-3, autowired

I played around with the Spring version in my application today. I started out at Spring 3.1.1 and when I moved to Spring 3.1.3 my application began throwing a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException during startup.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   matching bean of type
>   [nl.my.product.properties.Properties] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

I configured the Properties bean in the application context like this:

```
<!-- Gather properties from environment.properties in a map -->
<bean id="systemProperties" class="nl.my.product.properties.Properties">
    <property name="propertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="email.from.address" value="${email.from.address}"/>
            <entry key="site.host" value="${site.host}"/>
            <entry key="site.protocol" value="${site.protocol}"/>
            ...
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And I autowired the bean into many of my controllers and services, like this:

```
@Autowired
public ArticleController(ArticleService articleService, PageBlockService pageBlockService, Properties systemProperties) {
    this.articleService = articleService;
    this.pageBlockService = pageBlockService;
    this.properties = systemProperties;
}
```

Any clue as to why Spring is unable to find my bean since Spring 3.1.3? I tried moving the Properties bean to a package to was not also scanned for components, but that doesn't solve the problem.

When I annotate the Properties bean with @Component Spring does pick it up, but then the properties map is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working when I removed the `id="systemProperties"` from the bean definition